# How to add timePicker using fragment?

Tags: java, android, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have 4 `timePicker` in my app. The `timePicker` dialog will pop out when the user double click on the `editText`. But sometimes when I accidentally click more than two times, the app crashed and said that the fragment already added. How can I fix this? Insted of clicking the editText twice, I want the timePicker dialog shown by just one click on the `editText`.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.editTextTI1) {
            tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_START_DATE);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
        }
        if (id == R.id.editTextTO1) {
            tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_END_DATE);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
        }
        if (id == R.id.editTextTI2) {
            tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_START_DATE1);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
        }
        if (id == R.id.editTextTO2) {
            tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_END_DATE1);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
        }
        if (id == R.id.editTextTI3) {
            tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_START_DATE2);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
        }
        if (id == R.id.editTextTO3) {
            tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_END_DATE2);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
        }
        if (id == R.id.editTextTI4) {
            tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_START_DATE3);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
        }
        if (id == R.id.editTextTO4) {
            tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_END_DATE3);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
        }

    }




    public static class TimePick extends android.app.DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        public static final int FLAG_START_DATE = 00;
        public static final int FLAG_END_DATE = 01;
        public static final int FLAG_START_DATE1 = 10;
        public static final int FLAG_END_DATE1 = 11;
        public static final int FLAG_START_DATE2 = 20;
        public static final int FLAG_END_DATE2 = 21;
        public static final int FLAG_START_DATE3 = 30;
        public static final int FLAG_END_DATE3 = 31;
        private int flag = 00;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void setFlag(int i) {
            flag = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofDay, int minute) {

            if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE) {
                start.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                b = start.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE) {
                end.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                c = end.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE1) {
                start1.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                d = start1.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE1) {
                end1.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                e1 = end1.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE2) {
                start2.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                f = start2.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE2) {
                end2.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                g = end2.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE3) {
                start3.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                h = start3.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE3) {
                end3.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                i = end3.getText().toString();
            }
```

**LogCat Error**

```
10-15 12:53:17.113    7943-7943/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 7943
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: TimePick{7c7eb96 #0 TimePicker}
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1219)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:715)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is so hardcoded and not easy to extend, which could lead to many bugs in future.
You should encapsulate general logic as max as you can, so in current case:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) v;
    if (tp==null || !tp.isAdded()){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        tp = new TimePick(editText);
        tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (tp.isAdded()) tp.dismiss();
}

public static class TimePick extends android.app.DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private EditText editText;

    public TimePick(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofDay, int minute) {
        editText.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
    }
}
```

this code won't try to create new time picker if any is on screen. You could pass target edittext to timePicker fragment. When you need values from these edittexts(your a,b,c,d... variables) you could read it when needed, not in onTimeSetMethod.

onStop method was provided to handle activity recreation cases. Here i just  hide active timepicker.

Comment: hi Beloo, thanks for taking your time to solve my problem. How can I pass other variables to timePicker fragment?

Comment: You could did that via contstructor, setter. Make sure you really need it. If you described for what do you need them i can be more detailed

Comment: As you can see I have 8 editText for Time In and Time Out...hope it ables to make you clear

Comment: Yep, i noticed that before, so what is the problem?. My snippet should work with all these timepickers and edittexts.

Comment: @Beloo I have many editText(start,end,start1,end1,start2,end2,start3,end3) but your example only provide one `editText`.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same `DialogFragment` instance twice, to fix this, check whether `TimePicker` is added with `getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("TimePicker")`.

Comment: Every time you call `tp.show(ft, "TimePicker")`, the `DialogFragment` is added thus the exception. Check it before the call or you can use a new instance each time since `DialogFragment` is removed when dismiss.

Comment: IMO it is good for you to use new instance of dialog, you don't have to implement a lot of boilerplate code to reset the state and the data structure, and, as one of your consideration, lightweight dialog has very little impact on memory allocation.

Comment: where can I find IMO?